# Google App Engine Standard with Java Sprint Boot REST - not working in GCLOUD server

Tags: java, rest, maven, spring-boot, google-app-engine

I managed to deploy and test the local version of my Java Spring boot RESTful application **locally*** using the guide provided [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/blob/master/appengine-standard-java8/springboot-appengine-standard/README.md).
Using the command **mvn appengine:run**, I manage to access the REST API without any issue (through eg: http://localhost:8080/setiaalam/amenities). Tested both browser and Postman.

Then, once I deployed it into GCLOUD, it always return 404. I thought probably it make needs some time to update the server, so even after minutes, or hours, it is still 404. The log doesn't give anything helpful apart from file not found 404. The command that i used to deploy is: **mvn appengine:deploy**.

If it got to do with setting such as the pom.xml or appengine-web.xml, which i dont think it is, since running localhost using the command **mvn appengine:run** have no issue at all.

Anyone have any idea what could be the possible cause? Again, I want to highlight that, this is problem on accessing RESTful API and not servlet.

**UPDATE part 2**

Added application.properties

```html
# Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
# This is for connecting between Google App Engine Standard in the Cloud with Google Cloud SQL
#spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://google/setiaalam?cloudSqlInstance=sa-community-1545365567756:asia-southeast1:setiaalam&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&user=root&password=setiaalam99?useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name=sa-community-1545365567756:asia-southeast1:setiaalam
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name=setiaalam


#spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://35.240.140.154:3306/setiaalam?useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = mypwd

spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

# Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# sa-community-1545365567756:asia-southeast1:setiaalam
```

**AND** the following error:

```html
Driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:google:mysql://sa-community-1545365567756:asia-southeast1:setiaalam/setiaalam
```

**UPDATE part 1**

Added appengine-web.xml (located src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/)

```html
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
  <runtime>java8</runtime>
<system-properties>
  <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties"/>
</system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

The web.xml (located src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Servlet 3.0 Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

The pom.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
 <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
 <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.venturearkstudio</groupId>
<artifactId>setia-alam-community</artifactId>
<version>0.0.2</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>setia-alam-community</name>
<description>description for this said project</description>

<properties>
 <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <!-- NEEDED FOR GOOGLE APP ENGINE TOMCAT EXCLUSION-->
   <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <scope>compile</scope>
 </dependency>
 
 <!-- NEEDED FOR GOOGLE CLOUD SQL -->
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
  
  <!-- NEEDED FOR GOOGLE APP ENGINE JAVAX.SERVLET-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
 <!-- NEEDED FOR GOOGLE APP ENGINE SCOPE TEST-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
 
 <!-- NEEDED FOR GOOGLE APP ENGINE JETTY LOGGING -->
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
     <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
 
 <!-- NEEDED FOR HIBERNATE -->
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
  <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
 </dependency>
 
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
 <!-- The following is needed to be excluded due to Google Cloud needs. -->
  <exclusions>
         <exclusion>
             <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
             <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
         </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
 </dependency>
 
 
 <!-- NEEDED FOR GOOGLE SERVICES -->
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.maps</groupId>
     <artifactId>google-maps-services</artifactId>
     <version>0.9.1</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
     <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
     <version>2.8.5</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
 
</dependencies>

<build>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  </plugin>
  
      <!-- NEEDED FOR GOOGLE APP ENGINE MAVEN PLUGIN -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
      <cloudSdkPath>C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk</cloudSdkPath>
     </configuration> 
        </plugin>
  
  <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.6</version>
   <configuration>
             <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
         </configuration>
    </plugin>
  
 </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

The app.yaml generated from deployed files (Stackdriver Debug):

```html
runtime: java8
inbound_services:
- warmup
derived_file_type:
- java_precompiled
threadsafe: True
auto_id_policy: default
api_version: 'none'
handlers:
- url: (/.*)
  static_files: __static__\1
  upload: __NOT_USED__
  require_matching_file: True
  login: optional
  secure: optional
- url: /
  script: unused
  login: optional
  secure: optional
- url: /.*/
  script: unused
  login: optional
  secure: optional
- url: /_ah/.*
  script: unused
  login: optional
  secure: optional
```

Comment: Please share your `appengine-web.xml`, `web.xml`, the deploy log output, and any logs from Stackdriver Logging.  Also take a look at the _Stackdriver Debug_ view (https://console.cloud.google.com/debug): it shows what was deployed for your project/instance/version on App Engine.

Comment: Hi @BriandeAlwis noted. I just added those require info into main post (above). Fyi, thanks to you, I managed to use the Stackdriver Debug view and compare the version deployed to the GCloud is the same as the 1 running locally, at least by checking the web.xml contains and application.properties.

Comment: Hi @BriandeAlwis, thanks this does solve the problem. However, I encounter a separate issue...As I trying to connect the App Engine Standard to the Google Cloud SQL 2nd generation. I updated the above with application.properties and the error from the Google Console. Can help?

Comment: You might want to look at the Spring Cloud GCP project: https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-gcp

Comment: @BriandeAlwis thanks a lot. I managed to fix it using your web.xml solution and re-authenticate my gcloud auth. Also, I still not sure why we need web.xml, i can't find back the URL/post, but I thought it is not needed to have web.xml when using Google App Engine Standard?

Comment: I'm pretty certain you need a web.xml — it's the only place that defines your servlet version — but you can skip most routing information providing you use annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `web.xml` to specify Servlet 3.1:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
  <display-name>Servlet 3.1 Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

I've filed a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/127881574).